# change header of page in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want my site header after page scroll to the bottom of Figure 1, Figure 2 changes. How should i write the code? Please help

[image]

Comment: Edit the question with the code you currently have.

Comment: Please give more details.. Not able to understand what you exactly want..

Comment: When scrolling the page to hide the yellow header

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('.sticky'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 100) sticky.addClass('fixed');
  else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
});
```